# Confusion about bounds for $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working on a limit that requires the squeeze theorem

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x^2(\sin(x)+\cos^3(x))}{(x^2+1) (x-3)}$$

For the bounds, the solution stated the following:

First, note that

$$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$$

And

$$-1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1$$

So that

$$-1 \leq \cos^3(x) \leq 1$$

Thus

$$-2 \leq \sin(x) + \cos^3(x) \leq 2$$

While it is technically true that the sum of the outputs of  $\sin(x)$ and $\cos^3(x)$ will always be greater than $-2$ and less than $2$, isn't this false in the sense that the range of  $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$ is not $[-2, 2]$?

What I'm driving at is that the range of possible outputs of function $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$ does not oscillate between $[-2, 2]$ as the inequality suggests.

Just thinking through this with the simpler function $\sin(x) +\cos(x)$, it would not make sense for the range to be $[-2, 2]$ for it suggests that there are $x$-values for which both sine and cosine are $-1$ or $1$ simultaneously, which we know is false. And since $\cos^3(x)$ is a modification of $\cos(x)$ the same line of reasoning holds.

Graphing $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$ we see the actual range is $[-1.172, 1.172]$

[image]

My question is why is it valid to use  $-2$ and $2$ as the bounds of $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$ despite not being the actual rannge values? Doesn't it falsely suggest that $\sin(x) + \cos^3(x)$ oscillates between $[-2, 2]$?

Problem can be found [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/squeezedirectory/SqueezePrinciple.html) (it's problem #7)

And the solution can be found [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/squeezesoldirectory/SqueezeSol.html#SOLUTION%207)

Comment: For a limit you are only trying to find a bound, not the tightest bound.

Comment: It says that $\sin x + \cos^3 x$ stays between $-2$ and $2$, which is fine. The inequality *does not* say that $[-2,2]$ is the range of the function, only that it contains it. Like you say it is possible to provide better bounds. It's like saying a pencil can fit in the Pacific ocean : sure it can, but the fact it can fit in a pencil box is more useful. However, if for a problem you were solving, it was sufficient to show that a pencil can fit inside the Pacific ocean, then you would just use that fact and move, rather than do the hard work of showing it fits inside a pencil box.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Ahh I see that makes much more sense now. So technically we could use any bounds $-c$ and $c$, where  $c$ is a constant, even something as letting the bounds be $-100$ and $100$.  I imagine that using $-2$ and $2$ as bounds is fairly convenient and provides a good enough "tightness." Thank you! :)

Comment: @Slecker Happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to find the exact upper and lower bounds to obtain the result indeed in this case it suffices to observe that $|\sin(x)+\cos^3(x)|\le 100$ and then

$$-\frac{100x^2}{(x^2+1) (3-x)}\le \frac{x^2(\sin(x)+\cos^3(x))}{(x^2+1) (x-3)}\le \frac{100x^2}{(x^2+1) (3-x)}$$

and apply squeeze theorem with

$$\pm \frac{100x^2}{(x^2+1) (3-x)} \to 0$$

Comment: Ah, I see so it doesn't even necessarily have to be a "tight" bound. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Slecker Exactly! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

An excellent answer has been provided above using squeeze theorem.

Note that
$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x^2(\sin(x)+\cos^3(x))}{(x^2+1) (x-3)}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sin(x)+\cos^3(x)}{(1+\frac{1}{x^2}) (x-3)} =\frac{C}{-\infty}\to 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

From the given solution, you should understand that what matters is that this factor is *bounded*. As the limit is zero anyway, the exact values of the bounds are irrelevant.

So one could have used the gross bracketing

$$0\le|\sin(x)+\cos^3(x)|\le|\sin(x)|+|\cos^3(x)|\le1+1$$

or just said "the factor is obviously bounded".

---

For tight bounds, find the extrema from

$$\cos(x)-3\sin(x)\cos^2(x)=\cos(x)\left(1-\frac32\sin(2x)\right)=0$$

and

$$\cos(x)=0\to\sin(x)+\cos^3(x)=\pm1,$$

$$\sin(2x)=\frac23\to\sin(x)+\cos^3(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt5}6}\pm\left(\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}6}\right)^3\\\approx\pm1.1720537521447$$